# Problema con reporte jasper al descargar pdf en jsp

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto java web donde tengo unos reportes creados en Jasper Report , el problema es que después de visualizar un reporte, si descargo el pdf, el sistema me muestra que solo lo puedo exportar en formato jsp, por lo tanto al querer abrir despues el pdf, este no se habre por no tener la extensión pdf.
En el código java se muestra correctamente el formato "Application/pdf", pero no se descarga como pdf.

Acá dejo el código

```
                        <%
                        try{
                        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
                        File reportFile=new File(application.getRealPath("reportes/reporteVuelosMasUsados2/reporteVuelosMasUsados2.jasper"));
                        Map parametros=new HashMap();


                        String fechaDesde=request.getParameter("txt_fecha_desde");
                        String fechaHasta=request.getParameter("txt_fecha_hasta");

                        parametros.put("fechadesde", new String(fechaDesde));
                        parametros.put("fechahasta", new String(fechaHasta));

                        byte [] bytes= JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parametros,conn);
                        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

                        ServletOutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
                        response.getOutputStream();
                        output.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        }
                        catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException ex)
                        {
                            ex.getMessage();
                        }
                    %>
```

Acá dejo imagen del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde más habría que modificar?

Comment: Que se podría hacer para que descargue en formato pdf?

Comment: Me podrían ayudar con este tema por favor.

Comment: Me podrían ayudar por favor ya que según mi código el documento debería guardarse en pdf según la linea de código : response.setContentType("application/pdf");

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, aun no he podido hacer que se descargue en pdf,alguien me podría ayudar por favor.